# Как получить доступ к сайту на локальном сервере в интернете

Tags: ubuntu, веб-программирование, сервер

На компьютере с Ubuntu на локальном сервере расположен сайт. Компьютер находится в организации, где я работаю, и интернет к этому компу идет по локальной сети. Также от провайдера имеется 1 внешний IP. Нужно сделать так, чтобы этот сайт был доступен и в интернете. Как мне этого добиться?

Comment: Добрый день! Этого можно добиться с помощью перенаправления портов. Все зависит что вы используете в качестве маршрутизатора , какое устройство раздает интернет в Вашей организации ?

Comment: Спасибо. А как именно это сделать? На примере какого-нибудь маршрутизатора

Comment: Для начала вам нужно проверить обращение по IP адресу (что естественно не так удобно как по доменному имени), в этом случае как правильно отметил @Andrey вам необходимо пробросить порт 80 (или другие, к чему привязывается локальный сервер) чтобы когда было обращение в браузере по внешнему IP в результате запрос шел на локальный типа 192.168.0.13, а вот как это сделать уже зависит от того какой компьютер/сервер/роутер принимает этот глобальный IP от провайдера и дает интернет в локальную сеть, с его настройки и надо начинать

Comment: Когда вы по IP адресу получите доступ к локальному компьютер а именно к локальному сайту вам нужно будет регистрировать доменное имя и привязываться к DNS серверам, но это обычно хостинги свои услуги предлагают создать и прилинковать доменное имя

Comment: @Soft , У каждого производителя это делается по разному (не имеет смысла описывать пример). Вам необходимо 1) узнать какой маршрутизатор в сети 2) гуглить port forwarding для этого маршрутизатора

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы.